# How can I install NodeJS 18 or the latest version in the old ec2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

My ec2 instance was created in 2018 or earlier, it supports to NodeJS 12 but I can not install NodeJS 18 or the latest version. where I using Amazon Linux. How can I install NodeJS 18 or the latest version in the old ec2 instance?

Trying to install using this command.

nvm install 18

Comment: Hello Mohib, Can you specify what's wrong with `nvm install 18` you wrote? Does this give any errors? If yes please edit your question and include the error logs.

Comment: when I was trying to install node 18 it did not provide any error but it's not installed.